# Stop Scrolling for CollapsingToolbarLayout when showing a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a `ViewPager` inside an `Activity` which shows two `Fragments`.

The activity has a `TabLayout` and a `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. The `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is nested inside the `AppBarLayout` with an `ImageView` to produce a parallax effect. The `TabLayout` is outside the `AppBarLayout` inside a `LinearLayout` with the `ViewPager`. Then there is a `FrameLayout` as well to show another `Fragment` over the `ViewPager` when the user clicks a button to show that `Fragment`.

The problem is that when you scroll the `RecyclerView` inside the `Fragment` that overlays on top of the `ViewPager` the `Activity` also scrolls and does the parallax effect. Essentially it scrolls both the `RecyclerView` inside the `Fragment` and the content inside the `ViewPager` as well.

Is there a way to stop scrolling for the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and only scroll content in the overlay `Fragment` when the user sees that `Fragment`?

This is what my XML Hierarchy looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />
    <!-- Two fragments inside ViewPager each containing a RecyclerView -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- User Clicks a button and fragment is added to this framelayout -->
<!-- This fragment overlays on top of the entire Activity layout -->
<!-- This fragment also contains a recyclerview -->
<FrameLayout/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If you don't want your activity to scroll your appbar then remove the layout_behavior attribute for your LinearLayout. I assume your fragment FrameLayout contains that layout_behavior?

Comment: Do you want your FrameLayout to be displayed full screen (covering the Toolbar) or below the Toolbar? If you move the FrameLayout outside of the CoordinatorLayout (covering the Toolbar), you can then override the on touch listener to prevent the CoordinatorLayout from scrolling in the background.

Comment: @McGuile that makes sense, maybe I can programmatically remove the scrolling behavior when the Fragment overlays the Activity

Comment: @blackcj below the toolbar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout` operate via `onNestedScroll` callbacks from children. If you have a scrolling child, you can stop it from effecting its parent/s by disabling this callback:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Posted this earlier on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779123/need-to-disable-expand-on-collapsingtoolbarlayout-for-certain-fragments/. But it was largely ignored. Wondering if it actually solves your issue. If not, perhaps you can find your answer in that question. :3

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out but your answer is very short.

Comment: Can you give me a detailed answer with thorough explanation of WHY this occurs? I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score -4):

Try a nestedscrollview instead of linearlayout.

Comment: This answer definitely deserves a vote down, not only did you not consider my application specific requirements but suggested a completely different approach one that I am already familiar and is usually a fairly basic example, for example most new design support library example start with a `NestedScrollView`. What if I wanted to not let the LinearLayout container scroll off the screen? Your answer is also 6 words, vague and obscure it does not help me nor anyone else viewing this question.

Comment: Nicely articulated, sir.