# Toolbar expands on swipe down

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

In my application I have a collapsing Toolbar. If I start a specific Fragment I want to collapse the Toolbar so it behaves like a "normal" one and that the user can not expend it by himself. Here is my layout which I use for my Toolbar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/drawer_background"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="172dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:minHeight="100dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I also can collapse the layout from code like so:

```
appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false);

final AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsingToolbarLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(0);
collapsingToolbarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But this does not help. If the user swipes down from the Toolbar it will expand.

Do you have any ideas why?

Comment: How about setting the `AppBarLayout` height programmatically, so that it matches the height of your Toolbar? That way it would have nowhere to expand to.

Comment: There seems to be a mess with scroll flags in ImageView and Toolbar in your layout. Try to remove them too.

Comment: @IlyaPolenov I changed both to `scroll|enterAlways` but this do not change anything. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Try collapsingToolbarLayout.requestLayout(); method after applying these flags could help ..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The core problem is that there is no  `CollapsingToolbarLayout.lock();` method up until now (v23.2.1 of support design). Hopefully, this feature will be included in a future version. Until then, I'm suggesting the following workaround:

You can collapse and lock your toolbar with:

```
appbar.setExpanded(false,false);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appbar.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_height);
```

and unlock it with:

```
 CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appbar.getLayoutParams();
 lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.nav_header_height);
```

However, with the above code a problem occurs:

when forcefully collapsing CoordinatorLayout the title of our Toolbar is gone and `CollapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(CharSequence title);` no longer works. To fix that we add a TextView in our Toolbar and manipulate its visibility accordingly.  (we want it "gone" in a fragment that has its toolbar 'unlocked' and "visible" in a fragment that has its toolbar 'locked'.

We have to set TextView's `android:textAppearance` to be the same with CollapsingToolbarLayout's `app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance` to be consistent and avoid disrupting the user with different toolbar text sizes and colors.

In summary, with an interface like this:

```
public interface ToolbarManipulation {
    void collapseToolbar();
    void expandToolbar();
    void setTitle(String s);
}
```

implemantations like these:

```
@Override
    public void collapseToolbar(){
        appbar.setExpanded(false,false);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appbar.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_height);
        toolbarCollapsedTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void expandToolbar() {
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appbar.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.nav_header_height);
        toolbarCollapsedTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(String s) {
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(s);
        toolbarCollapsedTitle.setText(s);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.invalidate();
        toolbarCollapsedTitle.invalidate();
    }
```

and main xml like this:

```
....
  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBar"

            >
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_collapsed_title"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBar"
                        />
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
......
```

you can lock and unlock your Toolbar as you like. Your fragments should call these functions in their onResume();

I've uploaded an example implementation [here](https://github.com/AValsamis/ToolbarPlays).

Note: This is just a workaround and obviously not the cleanest solution. We're waiting for a newer version of com.android.support to resolve this.

Comment: Nice thank you for this great answer. I hoped that someone refers to the support library and their limitation so thank you for this detailed answer!

Comment: what is default toolbar_height ? @Sevle

Comment: 48dp for landscape and 56dp for portrait, source: https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html

Comment: There is a small issue the text of the title in the toolbar jump a bit when you pressback, also I suggest to change it's style to inherit from @style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title instead of  @android:style/TextAppearance.Medium

Comment: Thank you man )) spent like a day to solve this problem finally did it with ur solution perfect) working as expected

Answer (score 13):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams(); 
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior(); 
behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
        return false;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the height of the AppBar. It works for me.

```
public void lockAppBar() {
    int appbarHeight = (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.your_fixed_appbar_height);
    getView().findViewById(R.id.my_appbar).getLayoutParams().height = appbarHeight; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do `findViewById(R.id.image_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);` where `image_view` is the id of the **imageView** in the **collapsing toolbar.** But if you want to do it for a specific fragment I suggest calling the same using fragment- activity communication.

Answer (score 2):

None of the provided solutions worked for me except this one. With this solution, i can easily manage the state of collapsing toolbar. This will prevent expanding/enable collapsing of collapsing toolbar and set title for it.

```
public void lockAppBar(boolean locked,String title) {
    if(locked){
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
        int px = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 80, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = px;
        appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
    }else{
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, false);
        appBarLayout.setActivated(true);
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbarExpandHeight);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(true);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(title);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well try setting some parameters to toolBar, tabLayout programatically, I have `ViewPager` changing flags on onPageSelected(int)

```
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (position == 3) {//listen for scrolls only for Fragment 3
                params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
                toolBar.setLayoutParams(params);//hide as per scroll
                params = new AppBarLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
                tabLayout.setLayoutParams(params);//always visible
            } else {
                appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
                params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS_COLLAPSED);
                toolBar.setLayoutParams(params);//don't listen to scrolls
                tabLayout.setLayoutParams(params);//dont listen to scrolls
            }
        }
```

Use/Set above flags as you required. [AppBarLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing to do is to extend the class AppBarLayout.Behavior

```
public class AppBarBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {
  private boolean locked;

  public AppBarBehavior() {
    super();
  }

  public AppBarBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull AppBarLayout child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes, int type) {
    if (locked) return false;       // Lock when content scrolled
    else return super.onStartNestedScroll(parent, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes, type);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent, @NonNull AppBarLayout child, @NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    if (locked) return false;       // Lock when appBar swiped
    else return super.onTouchEvent(parent, child, ev);
  }

  public void lock(boolean locked) {
    this.locked = locked;
  }
}
```

Then set new layout_behavior in XML

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:layout_behavior="<full path to package>.AppBarBehavior">
```

And now you can manage locking with:

```
AppBarLayout appBar = findViewById(R.id.main_appbar);
appBar.setExpanded(false, true);   // collapse appBar
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBar.getLayoutParams();
AppBarBehavior behavior = (AppBarBehavior) params.getBehavior();
behavior.lock(true);   // lock appBar
```