# How to show collapsing toolbar as collapsed without scrolling android

Tags: android, layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar layout. I have shown graph on it. So if there are no items to show in the graph I want to show the collapsing toolbar layout as collapsed or hidden or closed. Only the toolbar and title should be displayed and not the graph.

Here is the view :

[image]

I want to display only the toolbar where I have a menu icon on left side.

Layout code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.siddhi.googletaskmanager"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/parentPanel"
    android:background="@color/background">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:titleEnabled="false"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/expandedappbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.HorizontalBarChart
                    android:id="@+id/chart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:weightSum="1">


            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
                android:id="@+id/menu1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                app:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
                app:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_white_24dp"
                fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="end"
                fab:menu_labels_singleLine="true"
                fab:menu_backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">



                <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
                    fab:fab_size="mini"
                    fab:fab_label="List 1"
                    app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"/>

                <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
                    fab:fab_size="mini"
                    fab:fab_label="List 2"
                    app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"/>

                <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fab3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_list_white_24dp"
                    fab:fab_size="mini"
                    fab:fab_label="List 3"
                    app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"/>

            </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

            <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
                fab:fab_size="normal"
                app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorAccent"
                app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT:

My current code is this :

```
if(mItems.size()  == 0) {
                    mBarChart.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false,false);
                    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
                  //  lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_height);
                    lp.height = (int) (android.R.attr.actionBarSize);

                }
                else
                {
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
                    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.appbar_height);
                    mBarChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
```

dimension:

```
<dimen name="toolbar_height">128dp</dimen>
<dimen name="appbar_height">200dp</dimen>
```

How can I achieve this?
Thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this programatically using `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true/false)`.

```
if(yourGraphIsEmpty){
   appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
}else{
   appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
}
```

> The core problem is that there is no  CollapsingToolbarLayout.lock(); method up until now (v23.2.1 of support design)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018411/5921902) is a complete solution that really works well

Comment: good this works.. but, I can expand it later. I should not able to expand the appbar. How to do this? @David Seroussi

Comment: If I set scroll flag as 0 the graph is shown as well I can't collapse the toolbar. @David Seroussi

Comment: Edited again, linked to another answer

Comment: can you let me know what is default toolbar height? I tried to work with this solution. but if I set toolbar height as 89 dp it looks perfect on device size 800x1280 but not on smaller device than that , on smaller device the app bar can be scrolled. @David Seroussi

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the closest height is `56dp`

Comment: Or you can use `android.R.attr.actionBarSize` in code

Comment: i tried this   lp.height = (int) (android.R.attr.actionBarSize); , but when I scrolled it's never ending toolbar it got scrolled till the bottom of the screen. :-( @David Seroussi

Comment: i tried with 56 dp but it looks too small on the device screen 800x1280. @David Seroussi