# CollapsingToolbarLayout (AppBarLayout) disable expanding on scroll

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have this layout in `res/layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity_s">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:expanded="false"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:statusBarScrim="@color/whiteTransparentLight">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/wordImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am trying to disable it programmatically or in xml. I already tried using:

```
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitleEnabled(false);
    appBarLayout.setExpanded(false,false);
    appBarLayout.setActivated(false);
    CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
    if (params != null) {
        AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
        behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        params.setBehavior(behavior);
        appBarLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

But no success. The drawer will expand on scroll. What's the code I could use to prevent expanding?

> NOTE: I am using: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1` library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CollapsingToolbarLayout disable draw down expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469579/collapsingtoolbarlayout-disable-draw-down-expansion)