# Want to lock AppBarLayout for some fragments

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout

I want AppBarLayout to remain in collapsed state for some of the fragments and remained open for other..Basically, i am looking for a function call which will make appbarlayout collapse/uncollapse programatically.... I have tried almost all methods listed on this stack over flow page, but none is working for me. Can someone please help.

Similar stack over flow page , tried most of things here but notworking..
[Need to disable expand on CollapsingToolbarLayout for certain fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779123/need-to-disable-expand-on-collapsingtoolbarlayout-for-certain-fragments)

thanks for your time

```
Layout file 


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="app.com.navact.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="256dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="0dip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
         </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can call `appBarLayout.setExpanded(true)` to expand the app bar layout and `appBarLayout.setExpanded(false)` to collapse it.

To lock the app bar layout into the expanded or collapsed state, call `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` on the scrolling view that moves the app bar. That view will somewhere in the view hierarchy of the fragment in your fragment container.

Comment: This solutions works, but if you would tap on collapsed toolbar and swipe down, it would do it, since this solution locks only nested scroll and just collpase the toolbar. I am facing this problem at the moment and one more another problem which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65304976/access-view-on-content-main-xml-from-a-fragment?noredirect=1#comment115502514_65304976). If you have any ideas to help me with my problem, I would be very thankfull to you.